# ajax requests to rails 3 server getting cancelled when using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am running an e-commerce platform using spree 1.2.4 and Rails 3.2.11 and in the checkout process i am trying to run an ajax call back to my server to update some information. The entire checkout process uses SSL (https is in the URL). The ajax calls seem to be getting cancelled. I'm assuming its because of the SSL encryption. If i look in chrome, the HTTP status just says "(cancelled)". My ajax call is:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/orders/get_update_cart_fields'
    }).done(update_cart_fields);
```

I also have `ssl_required :get_update_cart_fields` in my orders controller

Anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it so my ajax calls work?

Comment: Is the web page loaded from the same https domain as is being used for the requests?

Comment: I believe so? the url that would be in the browser address when the ajax call is made is https ://domain.com/checkout/address; and the ajax request is going to http(s).www.domain.com/orders/get_update_cart_fields. I am not sure if i need to set up the ajax call specifically so it knows I'm using https instead of http?

Comment: I don't know if you can do this experiment, but try loading everything over http instead. if the requests still fail, then use of https is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Everything works when i run it locally without SSL

Comment: Can you run the query to the server directly through the browser (typing in the url, rather than ajax)? It's weird, because ajax definitely works over https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it. heres what i had to do to get it working:

ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        'url': location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + '/orders/get_update_cart_fields'
    }).done(update_cart_fields);
```

in orders_controller:

```
ssl_allowed :get_update_cart_fields
```

after i did both of those things, i got it working. According to many sources ajax calls should automatically determine whether its http(s) but for some reason i had to manually do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the web page is being loaded from an http domain, then an Ajax call to the same domain but using an https protocol is considered a cross-domain request. Normally this will fail because browsers enforce a [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The good news is that, for the vast majority of browsers, you can enable cross-origin resource sharing by configuring your server correctly. The details of how to do this depend on your server. See [this site](http://enable-cors.org/) for guidance and more information. Basically, the only requirement is that your server include the following header in the Ajax responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: its being loaded from https. for some reason stackoverflow decided to hide the https in the hyperlink when i typed it out.

Comment: @Zyren - Ah. I had the same problem when I posted my answer; had to edit it a bit to get the links to work. I suggest you try enabling CORS anyway and see what happens.